# Unable to connect to postgre db running on docker container which is running on GCP VM

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform, telnet, host

I am trying Postgres Database that is running as part of Docker container running in a Ubuntu 18.04 VM provisioned from GCP.
Have configured Postgres database port to port 5432 on Ubuntu 18.04 VM and opened up the port 5432 by editing firewall rule details and docker container is also running but its taking long to connect and then the connection is getting timed out when am using using the public IP of the VM.

The command I have used to create docker container is
`docker container create     --name container_name     -p 5432:5432     -h container_name     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password     postgres`

I guess I have taken care of the port forwarding also in docker.

Also in the firewall rules I have specified the source range as my local machine's IP. Changed it to 0.0.0.0 but didn't work in both scenarios.

Although it runs fine when I try to get response using localhost or private IP but not working with public IP
I have checked the the opened ports also it showing open using `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` . Also checked using `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` and the port 5432 seemed to be open just not responding to telnet using public IP.

Just not able to figure out why telnet is not responding when i'm running telnet HOST:PORT

Comment: I think you need to tell us something about the target VM that you are trying to reach.  What is installed on it?  What makes you think it is willing to accept incoming Telnet requests?  What OS are you running on the Compute Engine?  What if you use SSH to login to the Compute Engine and then use netstat to look at the ports?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have done port forwarding for your docker container port to the vm port, by default when you are running any application on docker you need to perform port forwarding to make it available to the outside world. You can verify this by connecting a serial console to your vm and by entering the localhost and respective port number http://localhost:. As `kolban` said you have to use netstat command for checking the ports open on your vm. Follow this [document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for performing port forwarding. After this check whether there are any IP table rules or any other internal firewall rules are blocking this port from communicating to the outside world.

Comment: The port forwarding is also done as you mentioned also checked the port using netstat it seems open but still the issue persists

Comment: @Talib Have you checked the internal firewall rules like iptables..?

Comment: Checked it everything seems ok custom iptables chains named DOCKER-USER and DOCKER are present.

Comment: @Talib Sorry for mentioning prometheus instead of postgres you can install pgadmin in the same machine and check in the serial console whether you can read data from your database or deploy one more container with sample UI application which can fetch data from your database and view if it is fetching data properly or not.

Comment: @Talib In parallel you can search the container logs or docker logs for any errors while deploying your application

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually moved on and ran the postgre sql in jupyterlab using sql magic. As it was not responding through IP address so wasn't able to ran in on SQL Workbench. It works fine in jupyterlab and yeah the container logs is fine without any error or exception

Comment: @Talib thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delay in previous response and happy coding.

Comment: @Talib can you upvote the answer if you consider my efforts are worth to be noted.